# ionic : how to filter data in a select element based on a another one

Tags: angularjs, select, filter, ionic-framework

I have 2 tables in my database named : transporteur and camion , each transporteur has many camions :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `camion` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `matricule` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `idTransporteur` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transporteur` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codeTransporteur` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `RS` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `camion`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `FK_1` (`idTransporteur`);
```

HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">transporteur</div>
    <select ng-model="transp">
        <option ng-repeat="x in transporteur">{{x[1]}}</option>
    </select>
</label> 


<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">matricule camion</div>
    <select ng-model="matriculeCamion" >
        <option ng-repeat="x in camion">{{x[1]}}</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('AddController',['$scope','$http','$state',function($scope,$http,$state){

  var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8180/ExtractDataSelect.php",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
  });

  request.success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
    $scope.camion=data.camion;
    $scope.transporteur=data.transporteur;   
  });

}])
```

I want to show the *camion* data based on the selected *codeTransporteur*.

Comment: Can you show me example output of `$scope.camion` & `$scope.transporteur` please?

Comment: the output on the application ??! @mhx

Comment: Yes, what does the request return in its succes function? (data.camion & data.transporteur)

Comment: it returns all data (camions and transporteurs ) .. there is no error while selecting all data from db @mhx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution .. I should just add a `ng-if` inside my select element, :

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">transporteur  </div>
            <select ng-model="transp" >
              <option ng-repeat="x in transporteur ">{{x[1]}}</option>
            </select>
          </label> 


           <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">matricule camion  </div>
            <select ng-model="matriculeCamion" >
              <option ng-repeat="x in camion" ng-if=" x[3] == transp">{{x[1]}}</option>
            </select>
          </label>
```